# Why does the quality and style on this Naruto Shippuden series differ from the regular one?

Tags: naruto

I was watching this episode of *Naruto* on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qkH4mxtsaw).

I would like to know why the quality and style of the anime differs from the regular one?

Comment: Looks like that's a cutscene from a videogame, if you look at the description.

Comment: that's not an episode, that's from the game as per the description of the video *"Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm 4 the Rabbit Goddess大筒木カグヤ"Kaguya Otsutsuki" vs Naruto"*

Comment: For all those thumb downs: I am not a hard-core anime watcher, so I thought it might be the last episode with such quality! :D Have fun!

Comment: I upvoted. Guys stop down voting this question. It's a valid generic question about a media platform for anime and has a proper answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part of the video's description reads (emphasis by me):

> Naruto,Sasuke,Kakashi Team 7 Vs Kaguya Ōtsutsuki Full Fight (English Sub) . **Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm 4** the Rabbit Goddess大筒木カグヤ"Kaguya Otsutsuki" vs Naruto,Sasuke Uchiha Perfect Susanoo Kakashi. Rinne Sharingan vs Byakugan. Kaguya's unstable Tailed Beast Transformation awakening,Final TruthSeeker Orbs ultimate jutsu. Previous Boss Battles;

So as you can see, that is not a video from an episode of the anime series, but rather a cutscene from the [Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto_Shippuden:_Ultimate_Ninja_Storm_4) videogame. The bottom-most part of the description also clearly states that this is from a game:

[image: screenshot from the video description section]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I haven't been played Naruto games (none!), so that was weird for me (regardless of what description says).